# How to remove indents from list items

Tags: html, list, text-indent

Here is my code. How do I remove indents from the list items? Where does the code go?

```html
<ul>
    <li>The comment</li>
    <li>The product(s) involved</li>
    <li>The source of comment</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which indents? You have unordered list where every element starts with marker. If you don't want them you use `list-style-type: none;`. That is basic information, you can find it literally anywhere, use google or w3 first.

Comment: Yes, I've used that. However, it seems to be stripped after saving. Might be an issue with the rich text editor I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a few lines of CSS (in a [style sheet](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)):

```css
.nobullets {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; /* Optional */
}
```

```html
<ul class="nobullets">
<li>The comment</li>
<li>The product(s) involved</li>
<li>The source of comment</li>
</ul>
```